# No callback from cordova-plugin-googleplus plugin after successful login

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, google-plus-signin

Google plus signin using cordova-plugin-googleplus in my ionic app is giving me an issue. After login, the success callback is not called.

```
      window.plugins.googleplus.login(
        {
            'scopes': 'email profile', 
            'webClientId': '**********', 
            'offline': true, 
        },
        function (obj) {
            alert('login success');
            //... user service called

        },
        function (msg) {
            alert('error: ' + msg);
        }
    );
```

In the above code snippet, neither alerts are called. When I check the adb logcat logs I find that the login was success:

```
    D/CordovaActivity( 1614): Incoming Result. Request code = 77552
    D/CordovaInterfaceImpl( 1614): Sending activity result to plugin
    I/GooglePlugin( 1614): In onActivityResult
    I/GooglePlugin( 1614): One of our activities finished up
    I/GooglePlugin( 1614): Handling SignIn Result
    I/GooglePlugin( 1614): trying to get account information
    W/CordovaPlugin( 1614): Attempted to send a second callback for 
    ID: *************
    W/CordovaPlugin( 1614): Result was: {**** correct user info ****}
```

Also interestingly, the window.plugins.googleplus.trySilentLogin works fine. 
I am using android physical device and also have facebook plugin among others.

Any pointers to solve this would be great.

Comment: do you have a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I using this plugin, and just deleted

```
'webClientId': '**********',
'offline': true,
```

So the plugin is works.